# How to download Mapbox iOS SDK 6.0 and later w/ cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, mapbox, .netrc

I tried just changing the pod file to have the version '6.1.0' but it ended up giving the error seen below:

[!] Error installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/vn/nddktsy562946cl3l6v3xd740000gn/T/d20200828-4095-1h1x36o/file.zip https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/mobile-maps/releases/ios/packages/6.1.0/mapbox-ios-sdk-dynamic.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.9.3 cocoapods-downloader/1.4.0'

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0    44    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401

Then I tried to (as seen in the limited mapbox documentation) edit the .netrc file in the computer's home directory and then tried to run pod install again but that also did not work. Anyone do this yet? Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Mapbox version 6, you will need to authorize your download of the `Maps SDK` with a secret access token with the `Downloads:Read` scope. To create a secret access token, follow the steps mentioned here https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/overview/#install-the-maps-sdk. Once created add the access token to your `.netrc` file in your home directory like this

```
machine api.mapbox.com 
login mapbox
password <SECRET ACCESS TOKEN>
```

Once the `.netrc` file is successfully configured, you should be able to install the mapbox sdk using cocoa pods

Answer (score 1):

The answers offered above are quite helpful but for an absolute beginner who has never encountered such an issue before and who is new to the UNIX scene, I had a hard time knowing how to configure the `.netrc` file.

As outlined before, go to your mapbox account and create a new secret token. Create an account if you don't have one then go to [MapBox Token's page](https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens) and click on `Create a Token`. In the next page, select all token scopes relevant to your project. Ideally, select all.
[image]

Once that is done, create the token and copy the token created somewhere safe.

On your PC or Mac, open Terminal and type `vim ~/.netrc`. I chose to use vim but you can use any other text editor such as `nano` i.e. `nano ~/.netrc`. It should open a vim edit section like this if the file does not exist or open the existing `.netrc` file.
[image]

Click `I` key on your keyboard to start editing and paste the following code;

```
machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password <paste your token here>
```

Replace the `<paste your token here>` with the token you copied earlier.

Once that is done, press the `ESC` key and then type `:wq` to save and exit vim. Your `.netrc` file should now be configured.